# Brace settings for methods and properties with Resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, code-formatting

How can I configure Resharper so that it places the opening brace for methods on the next line but places the opening brace for properties on the same line? Resharper doesn't seem to be able to configure methods and properties independently.

```
class Example 
{
    public bool Foo {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public bool Bar ()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am trying to replicate the settings for braces described in the [Mono Coding Guidelines](http://www.mono-project.com/Coding_Guidelines#Where_to_put_braces).

Comment: I guess there is no way to do it now. I've created a feature request http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-369621 , consider voting for it if you care.

Comment: I upvoted the issue on YouTrack it, even though I think those guidelines are horrible and inconsistent :)